# More than one Remote Desktop Session on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, rds

I have a Windows Server 2012 setup and I access it using Remote Desktop Connection.

If I'm connected and someone else connects, I get booted off.
Is there a way for me to still stay connected and when someone else connects, they get there own "session" and I stay on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Remote Desktop for Administration allows two Remote Desktop Services sessions.

Looks like there is a limit set for this in your case [[check if there are limits for a number of sessions]](https://support.managed.com/kb/a1810/windows-server-2012-has-one-rdp-session-by-default.aspx).

If your server is in a domain, then the limit could be applied via GPO.
If **Limit number of connections** policy is enabled then the default restriction would be 1 session.

[image]

Comment: do you know if this is possible to do on a client machine (or a machine on a domain)?

Comment: On a server not joined to a domain - you can configure this policy by editing local policy (cmd > gpedit.msc and then navigate to an appropriate policy).

If the server is a domain member, then this can be controlled thru the GPO. If you have access to Group Policy Mgmt snap-in and appropriate permissions - you can change this by editing the GPO.